Listening to JTabbedPane tab selection by user
How do you listen to JTabbedPane tab selection by the user?
Currently, we attach a ChangeListener, but the problem is ChangeEvents are published even when the user doesn't select a tab. Specifically, it's published when a tab is removed and tab indices are recalculated. When that happens, we don't want to perform the same logic we're supposed to perform on user selections. I don't want to go into the details (they would only confuse you), but it causes one pesky bug in our app, it's not just performance
To prove it, let me show you a snippet from the javax.swing.JTabbedPane#removeTabAt method
// triggers ChangeEvent
        if (selected > index) {
            setSelectedIndexImpl(selected - 1, false);

The tabs in the tabbed pane are supposed to be dynamic. Removing and adding them back follows the requirements of our application
Here's an MRE. Select the red tab and then click the buttons. "User selections" are handled even though the selected tab doesn't change (it's still the red one)
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class TabbedPaneDemo {
    private static JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private static JButton removeGreenTabButton;
    private static JButton restoreGreenTabButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tabbed Pane demo");
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JComponent createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(createTabbedPane());
        return panel;
    }

    private static JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(createRemoveTabButton());
        panel.add(createRestoreTabButton());
        return panel;
    }

    private static JButton createRemoveTabButton() {
        removeGreenTabButton = new JButton("Remove green tab");
        removeGreenTabButton.addActionListener(e -> removeGreenTab());
        return removeGreenTabButton;
    }

    private static void removeGreenTab() {
        tabbedPane.remove(0);
        restoreGreenTabButton.setEnabled(true);
        removeGreenTabButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private static JButton createRestoreTabButton() {
        restoreGreenTabButton = new JButton("Restore green tab");
        restoreGreenTabButton.setEnabled(false);
        restoreGreenTabButton.addActionListener(e -> restoreGreenTab());
        return restoreGreenTabButton;
    }

    private static void restoreGreenTab() {
        tabbedPane.insertTab("Green tab", null, createGreenPanel(), null, 0);
        removeGreenTabButton.setEnabled(true);
        restoreGreenTabButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private static JTabbedPane createTabbedPane() {
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Green tab", createGreenPanel());
        tabbedPane.addTab("Red tab", createRedPanel());
        tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 150));
        tabbedPane.addChangeListener(e -> handleUserSelection());
        return tabbedPane;
    }

    private static Component createGreenPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        return panel;
    }

    private static Component createRedPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        return panel;
    }

    private static void handleUserSelection() {
        // this is supposed to happen only on user tab selections
        System.out.println("Handling user tab selection...");
    }
}

Java 8

In the button's (both buttons) action listener, you can remove the tabbed pane's change listener at the start and add it again at the end of the action. This way you can avoid change events firing when buttons are pressed.

The below assumes that each tab (in the JTabbedPane) has a unique title. Essentially, you need something unique for the below to work so if it's not the title, then you can use a second client property.
Save the title of the currently selected tab in a client property. The below code uses a property key which is the string GEORGE, but note the [property] key is Object which means it can be anything. In method handleUserSelection, check whether the title of the currently selected tab is different to that of the client property. If it is then you know that the selection has changed.
Here is the code from your question with changes as described above.
(More notes after the code.)
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class TabbedPaneDemo {
    private static JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private static JButton removeGreenTabButton;
    private static JButton restoreGreenTabButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tabbed Pane demo");
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JComponent createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(createTabbedPane());
        return panel;
    }

    private static JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(createRemoveTabButton());
        panel.add(createRestoreTabButton());
        return panel;
    }

    private static JButton createRemoveTabButton() {
        removeGreenTabButton = new JButton("Remove green tab");
        removeGreenTabButton.addActionListener(e -> removeGreenTab());
        return removeGreenTabButton;
    }

    private static void removeGreenTab() {
        tabbedPane.remove(0);
        restoreGreenTabButton.setEnabled(true);
        removeGreenTabButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private static JButton createRestoreTabButton() {
        restoreGreenTabButton = new JButton("Restore green tab");
        restoreGreenTabButton.setEnabled(false);
        restoreGreenTabButton.addActionListener(e -> restoreGreenTab());
        return restoreGreenTabButton;
    }

    private static void restoreGreenTab() {
        tabbedPane.insertTab("Green tab", null, createGreenPanel(), null, 0);
        removeGreenTabButton.setEnabled(true);
        restoreGreenTabButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private static JTabbedPane createTabbedPane() {
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Green tab", createGreenPanel());
        tabbedPane.addTab("Red tab", createRedPanel());
        tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 150));
        tabbedPane.putClientProperty("GEORGE", "Green tab");
        tabbedPane.addChangeListener(e -> handleUserSelection());
        return tabbedPane;
    }

    private static Component createGreenPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        return panel;
    }

    private static Component createRedPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        return panel;
    }

    private static void handleUserSelection() {
        String george = (String) tabbedPane.getClientProperty("GEORGE");
        int current = tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
        String title = tabbedPane.getTitleAt(current);
        if (!george.equals(title)) {
            tabbedPane.putClientProperty("GEORGE", title);
            System.out.println("Handling user tab selection...");
        }
    }
}


JTabbedPane automatically sets the selected index to the first tab added. Hence value of [client] property GEORGE is initially Green tab.
Adding or removing tabs changes the selected index, however the titles of each tab do not change.
Inspiration for my answer came from answer to this SO question.

When I run the above code, Handling user tab selection... is only printed when the selected tab changes. If the Red tab is selected and I press Remove green tab button, then Handling user tab selection... is not printed.

Thank you. That's how I first solved it. But I think I found a better solution. To create a separate SelectionEvent handled by a custom JTabbedPane extension (we need one anyway)

ChangeEvent is fired whenever any change happens, you have to additionally control and check the selected tab index (e.g. with ((JTabbedPane) event.getSource()).getSelectedIndex()) to be able to figure out if the selection actually changed.
You could achieve this e.g. by a custom ChangeListener that keeps track of currently selected tab and invokes specific code when that selection changes.

But index is not a reliable metric. The same tab can have different indices within the same run

In such case you may need to store an actual tab as a last selected one - at the time the event is fired though only one tab is at a given index. So when event is fired, check the index, fetch the tab at that index and compare it with whatever tab was marked as last selected. You can also use some unique identifier of each tab if you do not want to store tab itself.
